# Cannot type hashtag in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, ide

I'm having weird problem, I'm using shortcut AltGr+X or Ctrl+Alt+X to type # hashtag symbol in the code editor. However, even though I don't have any binding in eclipse for this shortcut, I can't type this symbol. Other symbols such as @ (AltGr+V) work normally. I can also copy-paste # that I type anywhere else.

Here are my key-bindings:
https://textuploader.com/1c2qw

Is there something wrong in my configuration or am I doing something wrong or is it a bug?

Edit: After applying "Show key binding when command is invoked" I can confirm no command is being run, however nothing is typed.

Comment: Maybe a shortcut for `#` isn't needed. What keyboard do you use?

Comment: @NikitaDemodov I'm using CES (Czech) keyboard layout, I can type # using Shift+3 on ENG (United states) layout

Comment: Does typing `@` work? And what OS are you using?

Comment: @NikitaDemodov yes, as mentioned, I can type @ without any problems. I'm using Windows 10

Comment: OK, so, for some reason, eclipse doesn't recognise altGR+X. I know that because assigning a shortcut to it will work but you can't actually use that shortcut. That also means that it's not a predefined shortcut. It also works independent of what OS you're on and what keyboard you use. At this point, we can only guess why this Is like this. If you don't find a good reason for this, I suggest you report a bug at (https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi)

Comment: reported as a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Workaround:

- select menu Window → Preferences
- expand General → Keys
- search for Run Gradle Test
- click Unbind Command
- click Apply and Close